# Inquiry about compiler warning(compiling C program)

Tags: c

This is the code I'm compiling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    printf("Table of temperature conversions\n");
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 10;

    celsius = lower;
    while(celsius <= upper){
        fahr = (9.0/5.0)*(celsius + 32.0);
        printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", celsius, fahr);
        celsius = celsius + step;
    }
}
```

And I get the following warning:

warning: type specifier
      missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

I was just curious, what variable is it complaining about not having a typing?

Comment: `main(){...}` was valid in very old versions of C. In modern C, the correct definition is `int main(void){...}` (if the program doesn't use command-line arguments).

Comment: This code is from K&R. If you have K&R2 then invoke your compiler in C89 mode (for gcc, that is `-std=c89`).  If you have K&R1 then you're on your own..:)

Answer (score 3):

The prototype for `main` should be:

```
int main(void) {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

If it is to take the command-line arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

The return type (`int`) is required.

Answer (score 0):

It is not complaining about a variable, but about the main function.

You should type `int main()` to suppress that warning.